# Extract frames from Video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

i am working on an app where i allow user to shoot a video and then capture the frames of the video every second and write the images to documents directory.I compiled the iFrameExtractor project which works fine on simulator but shows errors when running on device.Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the [`thumbnailImageAtTime:timeOption:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Method from the [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Class.

Comment: thanx Meccan,i will try this out but does this keep the image quality at its best?

Comment: i think the image resolution of the returned image is the same as the video resolution.